# Lucene's WordnetSynonymParser

Tags: lucene

I am trying to use Lucene's WordnetSynonymParser class to create a synonym filter, but I'm not sure which of the prolog files I'm meant to be passing into the parse() function.

The documentation says:

> See http://wordnet.princeton.edu/man/prologdb.5WN.html for a
>   description of the format.

so I've downloaded the prolog files, but I'm not sure which ones I should be passing in, and how I go about it.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks for your help

EDIT:

Thanks to femtoRgon for pointing me in the direction of wn_s.pl. I have now got the following code:

```
  Analyzer tempanalyzer = new SimpleAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);

  WordnetSynonymParser synparser = new WordnetSynonymParser(true, true, tempanalyzer);

  FileReader doctoread = new FileReader("wn_s.pl");

  synparser.parse(doctoread);

  SynonymMap synmap = synparser.build();


  Analyzer analyzer = new Analyzer() {
      @Override
       protected TokenStreamComponents createComponents(String fieldName, Reader reader) {



        EnglishAnalyzer enganalyzer = new EnglishAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_40);
        CharArraySet engstopset = enganalyzer.getDefaultStopSet();
         Tokenizer source = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_40, reader);
         TokenStream filter = new SynonymFilter(source, synmap, true);
         filter = new StandardFilter(Version.LUCENE_40, filter);
         filter = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_40, filter);
         filter = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_40, filter, engstopset);

         /*TokenStream filter = new StandardFilter(Version.LUCENE_40, source);
         filter = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_40, filter);
         filter = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_40, filter, engstopset);*/
         return new TokenStreamComponents(source, filter);
       }
     };
```

which I then plan on passing into IndexWriterConfig, however I get the following compile error:

```
IndexFilesDB.java:133: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method parse(java.io.FileReader)
location: class org.apache.lucene.analysis.synonym.WordnetSynonymParser
synparser.parse(doctoread);
```

I still don't fully understand WordnetSynonymParser, is it an error to do with the class or it just a simple error where the file is not being passes in correctly?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`wn_s.pl` contains the synset pointers (that is, it defines groups of synonyms), which is what you need for a synonym filter, to my knowledge.  I'd start with that.